# Problema tamaño labels jpgrahp php

Tags: php

hola tengo una consulta en la cual genero un grafico con el framework jpgraph el problema es que los label son tan grandes que estan juntos todos, aca abajo dejare la imagen y se daran cuenta.

¿Como podria arreglar eso?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria útil que agregaras tu código donde generas el gráfico para poder ser mas específicos al ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo seria girar tu texto

```
$labels=array("Texto muy grande","Texto muy grande","Texto muy grande","Texto muy grande","Texto muy grande","Texto muy grande");
$barras = new Graph(400,240);
$barras ->xaxis->SetTickLabels($labels);
$barras ->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
```

Comment: gracias estimado me sirvio de mucho tu ayuda